# Dataset Binding stored procedures update/insert/delete

Tags: c#, .net, database, ado.net, dataset

I am currently having a problem since the DB has been changed.

I am using Datasets for a c# application, and there is a user management system. 
For the security issues, our current DB design is like

1. user log into app.
2. DB returns a session ID
3. On use of any other stored procedures, a session ID must be specified.

BUT, the DB didn't request session ID before.

Since I am using the datasets, I used update/insert/delete stored procedures with

"TableAdaptor Configuration Wizard". 
Bind Commands to Existing Stored Procedures
    (choose stored procedures to call and specify any required parameters)

Now, it seems like I have to specify session ID for Insert/Update/Delete stored procedures. 
How do I specify session ID parameter here? 
It seems like I have to pick one return parameter variable from a select statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you would specify a session or GUID parameter to your insert/update/delete stored procedures. That would provide some sort of locking so that you only update/delete the latest copy of your records. Obviously you need to add a session or GUID field to you tables. Abd yes, every time you make a change to the underlying row in database you need to explicitly include an update or insert on that field.